# Cannot lipo arm64 .a files of iOS device with iOS simulator on Apple Silicon

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-silicon, lipo

Shell commands as below,

```
$ lipo -info libyuv-device.a
Architectures in the fat file: device/libyuv.a are: armv7 arm64
$ lipo -info libyuv-simulator.a
Architectures in the fat file: simulator/libyuv.a are: arm64 x86_64
$ lipo -create libyuv-device.a libyuv-simulator.a -output libyuv.a
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: libyuv-device.a and libyuv-simulator.a have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

How to lipo multiple arm64 .a files of iOS device and iOS simulator (on Apple Silicon, e.g. M1) into one single .a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should output a XCFramework.

1 - Use `lipo` to combine architectures per platforms like you did.

2 - Then use `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` to combine the platforms.

`xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library libyuv-device.a -library libyuv-simulator.a -output libyuv.xcframework`

Comment: It looks like the correct argument that needs to be passed is `-create-xcframework`, not `-create-framework`